# Seeing if a user has a permission WITHOUT discord.ext

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there anyway to see if a user has permission to run a command without using discord.ext. The code I made was this:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import discord
lockedChannelName = ""
lockedChannel = 0
lockedTime = ""
locker = ""
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
    async def on_message(self, message):
        global lockedChannelName
        global lockedChannel
        global lockedTime
        global locker
        if message.content == "!lockbothere":
            lockedTime = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
            lockedChannel = message.channel.id
            lockedChannelName = message.channel.name
            locker = message.author.name
        if message.content == "!unlock":
            lockedChannel = 0
        file = open("logs.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
        if message.author != self.user and True if lockedChannel == message.channel.id or lockedChannel == 0 else False:
            file.write(str(message.author) + ": " + message.content + "\n\n")
        file.close()
        if message.content == "!logs":
            file = open("logs.txt", encoding="utf-8")
            if message.channel.id != lockedChannel and lockedChannel != 0:
                await message.channel.send("Note: The logs were locked by " + locker + ". The text channel that was locked was " + lockedChannelName + ", it was locked at " + lockedTime + " GMT")
            if lockedChannel != 0:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Logs in this channel", description="All Messages In " + lockedChannelName)
            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Logs in this channel", description="All Messages In This Channel")
            embed.add_field(name='The Logs!', value=file.read())
            await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
            file.close()
        if message.content == "!clearlogs":
            with open("logs.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8"):
                pass
            await message.channel.send("Succsessfully Deleted Logs")
bot = MyClient()
bot.run("lol nope")
```

What I am going for is to make !clearlogs, !lockbothere, and !unlock only available to admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the boolean value of their administrator permission as follows:

```py
administrator = [p for p in message.author.guild_permissions if p[0] == "administrator"][0][1]
if administrator:
    #do some stuff
```

What's happening there is using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it) I'm iterating through the message author's permissions, which are tuples (e.g. `('administrator', True)`), and it checks the first element of the tuple - the permission name - and then returns the boolean value if it matches the specified permission name.

Keep in mind that these are guild permissions, and may differ from [channel-specific permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.permissions_in).

To see all the permission names you can search for, try running:

```py
perm_names = [p[0] for p in message.author.guild_permissions]
print(perm_names)
```

Comment: @1BadAtPython No worries, I'm always around if you need anything! Good luck with the bot :)